# "Identifier" Undeclared Identifier

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

Right now i try to change character set on my code from multibyte to unicode but when i compile this code i got an error, this is my error

```
error C2065: 'LtszCommConfigFile' : undeclared identifier
```

I dont know why this happen ?, i already declare `LtszCommConfigFile` identifier but still i got that error

this is my complete code

```
CString CCommApiHelper::GetTerminalNum(LPCTSTR  lpszCommonPath, BOOL bIsCyber)
{
    TCHAR                   tszCommConfigFile[MAX_PATH] = {0, };
    TCHAR                   tszTermNum[9] = {0, };
    CString                 strTermNum;

    _stprintf(tszCommConfigFile, L"%s\\CommInfo.ini", lpszCommonPath);

    if ( GetPrivateProfileInt(L"TEST_INFO", L"IS_TERM_ID", 0, tszCommConfigFile) == 1 )
    {
        GetPrivateProfileString(L"TEST_INFO", L"TERM_ID", L"A0000000", tszTermNum, sizeof(tszTermNum), tszCommConfigFile);
        strTermNum = tszTermNum;
        return      strTermNum;
    }

    int x1, x2, x3, x4;
    x1 = GetPrivateProfileIntA("IP_INFO", "A_CLASS", 0, _T(tszCommConfigFile));
    x2 = GetPrivateProfileIntA("IP_INFO", "B_CLASS", 0, _T(tszCommConfigFile));
    x3 = GetPrivateProfileIntA("IP_INFO", "C_CLASS", 0, _T(tszCommConfigFile));
    x4 = GetPrivateProfileIntA("IP_INFO", "D_CLASS", 0, _T(tszCommConfigFile));

    if ( (x2 / 10) == 10 )                          tszTermNum[1] += '1';       // 105 or 109
    else if ( (x2 / 10) == 20 )                     tszTermNum[1] += '2';       // 205 or 209
    else                                            tszTermNum[1] += '0';   

    _stprintf(&tszTermNum[2], L"%03d%03d", x3, x4);
    strTermNum = tszTermNum;
    return      strTermNum;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Post complete code so atleast your identifier in the error can appear in code itself

Comment: You can only apply the `_T` macro to string literals, not variable names. But ask yourself if you really want/need to compile *both* ANSI and Unicode versions of the same code, otherwise drop those `TCHAR` and `_T` altogether, and use the wide versions across.

Comment: Your title says your variable starts with L, yet it starts with t. I assume you mean L"...".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_T` is for string literals only (e.g. "hello world"). You cannot use it on variables.

`_T` and `TEXT` and `TCHAR` and `LPCTSTR` etc is ancient history, used in the 1990s when people wanted to write code that worked on both Windows 95 and Windows XP. There is no reason at all to use them in modern code.

Instead use `char` and related types for narrow characters (ASCII) and use `wchar_t` and related types for wide characters (Unicode).

Your specific error seems to be using `GetPrivateProfileIntA` when you should have used `GetPrivateProfileIntW`. i.e.

```
x1 = GetPrivateProfileIntW(L"IP_INFO", L"A_CLASS", 0, tszCommConfigFile);
```